# Additional Table of Contents in Appendix

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

In the appendix of a document I want to add an additional table of content to represent the following drawings.

Please consider the following example code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}

\appendix
\section{Appendix 1}
\section{Appendix 2}

% Example of the structure of the additional table of content just for appendix
1.000.000               Fertigungskonzept       1
   1.100.000            Baugruppe               2
      1.110.000         Unterbaugruppe          3
         1.111.000      Unter-Unterbaugruppe    4
            1.111.001   Einzelteil              5
            1.111.002   Einzelteil              6
         1.112.000      Unter-Unterbaugruppe    7
           1.112.001    Einzelteil              8
           1.112.002    Einzelteil              9
      1.120.000         Unterbaugruppe          10

%Here the actual drawings are following
\subsection{Fertigungskonzept}
\subsubsection{Baugruppe}
% etc...

\end{document}
```

The additional section in the appendix should not be shown in the main table of content, just in the appendix.

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: This means: A different section numbering system as well?

Comment: Have a look at the [`etoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that would be preferable.

Comment: @larkee, yes, but it is weird and illogical. You can't have more than 9 `Unterbaugruppen` before the counter 'overflows' ;-)

Comment: @larkee: Are you currently using any packages related to sectioning or the appendix?

Comment: @Werner No additional packages are used.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: The O.P. uses `article` as documentclass, there are no chapters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very short version, with `minitoc` and a special way of generating the (strange) section etc. counter values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\dosecttoc

\newcommand{\fillbefore}[1]{%
  \ifnum#1<10 
  00#1%
  \else
  \ifnum#1 <100
  0#1%
  \else
  #1%
  \fi
  \fi
}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secttocdepth}{5}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{30pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsecnumwidth}{20pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubsubsecnumwidth}{15pt}
\addtolength{\cftparanumwidth}{15pt}
\addtolength{\cftsubparanumwidth}{15pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Normal section}



\clearpage
\appendix


\adjuststc
\secttoc

\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{-5}} % preventing the appearance of the following sections in the normal ToC!

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\fillbefore{\the\numexpr100*\value{subsection}}.\fillbefore{0}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\the\numexpr100*\value{subsection}.\fillbefore{0}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{section}.\the\numexpr100*\value{subsection}+10*\value{subsubsection}.\fillbefore{0}}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{section}.\the\numexpr100*\value{subsection}+10*\value{subsubsection}+\value{paragraph}.\fillbefore{0}}
\renewcommand{\thesubparagraph}{\arabic{section}.\the\numexpr100*\value{subsection}+10*\value{subsubsection}+\value{paragraph}.\fillbefore{\arabic{subparagraph}}}
\section{Fertigungskonzept}
\blindtext[5]
\subsection{Baugruppe}
\blindtext[5]
\subsubsection{Unterbaugruppe}
\blindtext[5]
\paragraph{Unter-Unterbaugruppe}
\blindtext[5]
\subparagraph{Einzelteil 1}
\blindtext
\subparagraph{Einzelteil 2}
\blindtext
\paragraph{Unter-Unterbaugruppe}
\blindtext[5]
\subparagraph{Einzelteil 1}
\subparagraph{Einzelteil 2}

\subsubsection{Neue Unterbaugruppe}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]